# set variable equal to the user input lua

Tags: lua

When I was looking it up I was told to use the io.read() to get input yet when I run a simple code like this

```
name = io.read()
print (name)
```

It just outputs the word nil

Comment: What host environment are you running this script in?

Comment: I tried running this code as is on an online interpreter and on ilua and I got the same result

Comment: I had the code working earlier. Using the same interpreter(ilua) it had stopped the code and waited for an input. For some reason it now doesn't wait for input, it just continues.

Comment: Try `name = io.read() ; print (name)` if you're running the standard command line Lua interpreter `lua`.

Comment: @lhf How is that any different than what he has?

Comment: @cdhowie putting it on one line keeps the code in the same chunk when using the Lua interpreter. Check out the PiL 1.1 (http://www.lua.org/pil/1.1.html)

Comment: @Moop (a) You don't need the semicolon to put it all on one line. (b) Putting it all in one chunk would only be required if the code was `local name = io.read()`.

Comment: @cdhowie, if you press RETURN after typing `name = io.read()`, Lua will start reading `print (name)`, instead of interpreting it.

Comment: @cdhowie (a) yes, you don't need the semicolon to put it on one line, but it is perfectly acceptable practice (especially coming from a Lua creator...) (b) I am assuming OP was copy-pasting the code into the interpreter, doing so causes it to fail

Comment: @Moop (a) I'm only saying that it's not going to make a difference. Style is a different matter -- and as much influence as you have had, I do reject your appeal to authority. (I have been working on a Lua implementation, so this isn't exactly new ground for me.) (b) If you copy-paste then the second line may become input to the read operation, *which would not result in `nil` being output at all.* So it's unlikely this is related.

Comment: @cdhowie lol, look up the initials lhf... I think I will trust what he says. lhf is just giving a suggestion for OP's problem, and I was trying to explain to you his reasoning, 'how is that any different than what he has?' well, it is different when you enter the code into the interpreter

Comment: @sixhaunttau You will have to give us more information to solve your problem. We are only suggesting possible sources of error. Are you saving this code in a file and running it like `lua file.lua`? or are you typing it into the interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

As far as this goes, there are two easy ways.

You can use variables, of course.

```
Name = io.read() print(Name)
```

Or, I personally prefer using

```
print(io.read())
```

Simple enough, really.